Cannot read files with different paths
I'm trying to read csv file based on date in file name. Below is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import io

date_6='2024-05-15'
date_6_1 = '*' + date_6[:4] + date_6[5:7] + date_6[8:10] + '.csv'
for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\admin\Báo cáo ngày' and date_6_1):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
df

It worked well if I put data in same folder with Jupyter notebook, but if I changed Path of file, it did not work. For example.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import io

date_6='2024-05-15'
date_6_1 = '*' + date_6[:4] + date_6[5:7] + date_6[8:10] + '.csv'
for file in glob.glob(r'G:\New folder' and date_6_1):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
df

I don't know what wrong with it.
What should I change in this code?

why do you use and? Did you mean +?

Try to print(r'G:\New folder' and date_6_1). 'A' and 'B' is not doing what you think it does!

Since the part before and is always truthy, your code is equivalent to for file in glob.glob(date_6_1), which presumably works in the first case since you're in the correct path, but fails in the second one as the path should be absolute.

@mozway: So what should I change in Path to make it work? Instead of and I need to use +?

@mozway: Thank for your suggestion. I found the way. I need to change Path to something like r'G:/New folder/' and date_6_1

No, you should not use and. + is the correct operator for string concatenation (or use a library to concatenate paths).
